# How to update datatime attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just want to update the last_clicked_on:datetime attribute into current time.

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @feed_article = FeedEntry.find(params[:id])
    @feed_article.update_attributes(is_to_read: 'false')
    @feed_article.update_attributes(last_clicked_on: Time.now)
    @way = @feed_article.url
    redirect_to @way
  end
end
```

But the above code is not working. Please someone help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try

```
@feed_article.is_to_read = 'false'
@feed_article.last_clicked_on =  Time.now
@feed_article.save!
```

Anyway it's hard to help you with just this info. Issue might be in type of your columns, you can just misspell name of column... something else...

**PS**

Each `update_attributes` issue transaction in DB, so, you have 2 transactions instead of one... Code above will have only one transaction